# Using pandas group-by to select specific sub-groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe on the following form:

```
    id  grp  values1    values2
0   1   a_1  2          4
1   1   a_2  3          6
2   1   b_1  4          8
3   2   b_2  5          10
4   2   c_1  6          12
5   3   z_1  7          14
6   4   y_1  8          16
7   5   a_1  9          18
8   5   a_2  10         20
9   5   a_1  11         22
10  5   a_2  12         24
11  7   z_1  13         26
12  8   q_1  14         28
13  9   a_2  15         30
14  9   a_1  16         32
```

What I wand is a reduced data frame with the rows and ids containing "a_1" and "a_2" only for the ID-group like below.

```
    id  grp  values1    values2

7   5   a_1  9          18
8   5   a_2  10         20
9   5   a_1  11         22
10  5   a_2  12         24
13  9   a_2  15         30
14  9   a_1  16         32
```

The end data frame should have even numbers when doing a count on the id variable since the group values goes in "pairs", i.e. "a_1" and "a_2" together. Also, this should work for an arbitrary number of "group by columns" like the id column is.

The code for the dataframe is posted below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,7,8,9,9]
                   ,'grp' : ['a_1', 'a_2', 'b_1', 'b_2', 'c_1', 'z_1', 'y_1', 'a_1', 'a_2', 'a_1', 'a_2', 'z_1', 'q_1', 'a_2','a_1']
                   ,'values1' : [i for i in range(2,17,1)]
                   ,'values2' : [i for i in range(4,33,2)]
                  })
```

Thanks for considerations, time and input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could take the easier way and:

```
 filtered_df  = df.ix[(df['grp'] == 'a_1') | (df['grp'] == 'a_2')]
```

Comment: Right on the money, I know of the ix-method  but didn't think of it in this straightforward manner. Say that I wanted to include id group 1 also, which has 1 grp. value differing from the others and at the same time not taking any other grp which contains the extra value, i.e. "b_1".

Comment: Also, in addition to that, the numbers need to be even since there are occasions in my data where I have three lines, i.e. "a_1", "a_1" and "a_2" and that id should not be included in the reduced data frame!

Comment: I don't get what you mean, if you wanted to add another condition, follow the template above with another | and you'll be dine. For the second question, if youre talking about resetting the index, try df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply search for the conditions in the dataframe:

```
reduced_df  = df[(df['grp'] == 'a_1') | (df['grp'] == 'a_2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the "even numbers" solution like this, maybe not the most efficient but it got the job done:

```
# One row per id
pivot = df[['id', 'grp', 'values1']].pivot_table('values1', index = 'id', columns = 'grp', aggfunc = (lambda i: i.size)).reset_index()

# Take out the id rows which fulfills condition of being even numbers
pivot2 = pivot[pivot[['a_1', 'a_2']].sum(axis = 1) %2 == 0].reset_index()

# Sub-select rows from original table
df[df['id'].isin(pivot2['id'])]
```